# Option for my tags (filtering) while reviewing questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request

While reviewing opening or closing tags and other too. I feel many times skipping the questions because I am not aware of edited "code syntax" is right or not, or the particular question is *constructive* or not for the user of that language. So too many skips. To prevent this I suggest that we should use have `my tags` filtering in review section as well.

What do you say?